# Total number of ways such that the sum of elements is less than or equal to k

Tags: java, algorithm

Task: Find the number of possible ways to pick a single element from each array, such that their sum is less than `k`.

Here is my program looks like:

```
public static long process(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b, List<Integer> c, List<Integer> d, int k) {
    Collections.sort(a);
    Collections.sort(b);
    Collections.sort(c);
    Collections.sort(d);
    long total = 0;
    // four layer for loop to check all combinations of four arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        long v = a.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < b.size() && v < k; j++) {
            long v1 = b.get(j);
            for (int m = 0; m < c.size() && v + v1 < k; m++) {
                long v2 = c.get(m);
                for (int l = 0; l < d.size() && v + v1 + v2 < k; l++) {
                    long v3 = d.get(l);
                    if (v + v1 + v2 + v3 <= k) {
                        total = total + 1;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return total;   
}
```

This was asked during an interview, I see that when I have used it, the program failed for test cases saying time limit exceeded.

What is best approach to follow for this task?

Comment: Well, if I see four levels of `for` loops, I would be not remotely surprised that the time limit was exceeded. More than two levels of loops are in almost all cases questionable.

Comment: you could at least start summing up the values before going into the next loop and stop if that is already to high (this could help a little). But yes the best thing would be to get rid of that much for loops.

Comment: @JanezKuhar, I have fixed it now

Answer (score 5):

Let the length of the lists be `N`. Your approach is `O(N^4)`, which is likely to time out.
A simple yet faster approach would be:

1. Generate all pair sums (which are less than `k`) from arrays `A` and `B`. Store them in an array `X`. Complexity: O(N^2)
2. Generate all pair sums (which are less than `k`) from arrays `C` and `D`, store them in array `Y`. Complexity: O(N^2)
3. Sort arrays `X` and `Y`. Complexity: `O(N^2 logN)`
4. For each element in `X`, find the maximum element in `Y` such that their `sum < k`. Using binary search, complexity: `O(N^2 logN)`

Space complexity: `O(N^2)`, Time Complexity: `O(N^2 logN)`